# How to add item to arrayList and display it in another file in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web

I am working on my school project and I have problem with adding item to arrayList.

I need to add that specific product which is in button value to cartList after clicking on button and than display it in cart.jsp file the same way like in code below.

cart.jsp is in the same folder as index.jsp

This is my index.jsp:

```
<%
  ArrayList<Product> productList = null;
  ArrayList<Product> cartList = null;

  for (Product product : productList) { %>
   <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="product-info">
        <h3><%=product.getName() %></h3>
        <p class="price"><%=product.getPrice() %></p>
        <p class="category"><%=product.getCategory() %></p>
         </div>
        <form class="add-to-cart">
         <button value="<%=product%>">Add</button>
        </form>
  </div>
 <% }
%>
```

Comment: How is your application architected? Where does `cartList` live? What JSP prints out this menu and what JSP should add to the `cartList`?

Comment: Forget JSP for the moment. Have you learned how to create an object and put it into a list in pure java?

Comment: @Stewart yes, but I need to add it when someone on website click on that button, I thing there is no way to do it in pure java

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put an `action` into the form tag to target your `cart.jsp`, plus a `name` & submit type on the button to get a reference to the parameter:

```html
<form class="add-to-cart" action="cart.jsp">
    <button name="product" type="submit" value="<%=product%>">Add</button>
</form>
```

In the `cart.jsp`, get the product, look it up in productList and then add it to the cart list:

```
<%
   ArrayList<Product> productList = ...;
   ArrayList<Product> cartList = ...;

   String product = request.getParameter("product");
   for (Product p : productList) {
       if (p.toString().equals(product)) {
           cartList.add(p);
           break;    
       }
   }
%>
```